# How to check if the subversion URL is file or a directory using sharpsvn

Tags: c#, svn, c#-4.0, sharpsvn

First things first - I am sorry if you think this question is utterly stupid.

I am working on an application wherein the user can enter a SVN URL. It can either be a Directory or a file. I am using sharpsvn.

My aim is to somehow know if this url is a directory or a file.

For example : svn://svnrepository/Directory/pascal.cs 
or svn://svnrepository/DirectoryName

are both valid entries. Its my job to differentiate between the two and bring out the fact that the former is a file while the latter is a directory.

Can this be done using sharpsvn ?

Thanks and Regards
Gagan

Answer (score 4):

Condireng that it't only a wrapper over a real subversion, for you it *should* be enough to execute

```
svn info $path$
```

in the result set there has to be `Node Type` string. That would be give you description either it a `directory` or `file`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I am trying this using Shaprsvn and will update the results. Thanks once again ! :)

Comment: @Cagan: don't forget accept an answer if it will be correct answer.

Comment: Nope.. i will not forget to do that .. btw the name is gagan and not cagan :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use one of the following:

- [svnlook proplist](http://www.humbug.in/docs/svnbook-en/svn.ref.svnlook.html)
- `svn info`
- `svn ls ... -depth empty`

The last two are illustrated in "[Check that an svn repository url does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868033/check-that-an-svn-repository-url-does-not-exist)".

You can encapsulate those calls in SVNSharp hook following the examples of "[How can i get access to the SVN pre-commit message using SharpSVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380685/how-can-i-get-access-to-the-svn-pre-commit-message-using-sharpsvn)"

Comment: Thanks for taking time out for me @VonC. However I think Tigran's approach is the option that i will be interested in. The node type gives the exact type of the svn url ( if its a file or a directory) . if only i could make it work in LinqPad :)

Comment: @Gagan sure, my point was not about the svn command you choose, but more about pointing out a way to encapsulate it in SVNSharp.