# How to check out SVN external URL directly?

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I have a Subversion repository that contains some client files.  Some clients will use the standard files, but other clients will provide custom versions of the files.  To accommodate this, I've used svn:externals for the clients that will use the shared files.  So our structure is something like this:

```
svn
|+ top
   |+ shared
   |+ clients
      |+ custom1
      |+ custom2
      |+ shared1
      |+ shared2
```

The client "custom1" is a real folder in Subversion containing that client's customized files, and the client "shared1" is an svn:external property on the `/clients` folder which points to `/top/shared`.

What I was hoping for was that when I want to deploy a new client, I could simply export their folder to the server, using a command like:

```
svn export http://svn/top/clients/custom1 \\server\custom1
```

or

```
svn export http://svn/top/clients/shared1 \\server\shared1
```

This works fine for the customized clients because they have a "real" folder in Svn, but for the clients configured with externals, I get an error:

```
svn: E170000: URL 'http://svn/top/clients/shared1' doesn't exist
```

Is there a way that I can check out/export an "external" folder directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`http://svn/top/clients/shared1` is not a physical path in SVN but just a reference to your external. So, that is the reason you are not able to check out that directly.

To get rid of this, you can create `http://svn/top/clients/shared1` as an empty folder in SVN and you can give the svn:external property on the `http://svn/top/clients/shared1` folder to mke it point to `/top/shared` instead of `/clients` folder.

Then your check out will get a physical path to check out but you don't need to keep your actual content under this folder.

Comment: This would create an extra layer of folders which doesn't provide _exactly_ what I'm looking for, but it's close enough.

Answer (score 2):

What I ended up doing was using [svn ls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/868033/check-that-an-svn-repository-url-does-not-exist) to see if I was accessing a physical directory.  If it didn't exist then used the following command to get the target of my external:

```
svn propget svn:externals http://svn/top/clients/ | findstr "\<shared1\>" | sed "s/\(.*\)\s\(shared1\)/\1/"
```

`findstr` will get the single line for the property I'm looking for, and the `sed` command will parse out the target url (the part before the space).