# Export single file from SVN, possibly following externals

Tags: svn, svn-externals

I need to export a single file from SVN. My structure might look like this:

```
- trunk
   - file.py
   - anotherfile.py
   - folder
      - stuff.py
   - anotherfolder # <-- External!
      - magic.py
```

I'd like to be able to download any of these single `.py` files, given the structure. For example, any of these should work:

```
/trunk/file.py
/trunk/anotherfile.py
/trunk/folder/stuff.py
/trunk/anotherfolder/magic.py
```

For the first three, I understand I can use `svn export` like this:

```
> svn export http://host.xyz/trunk/folder/stuff.py c:\stuff.py
```

But this doesn't work if the file is in an external:

```
> svn export http://host.xyz/trunk/anotherfolder/magic.py c:\magic.py
svn: E170000: URL 'http://host.xyz/trunk/anotherfolder/magic.py' doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using one of the answers from [How to check out SVN external URL directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14840720/how-to-check-out-svn-external-url-directly) by finding out the target URL + target revision via...

```
svn propget svn:externals http://svn/myurl/
```

...and then using that target URL + revision to export the file.